# Terraform not able to detect the service delegation of subnet in plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hi I am trying to create service delagation in subnet

This is my main.tf code

```
  data "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
  for_each            = var.subnet
  name                = each.value["resource_group_name"]
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  for_each            = var.subnet  
  name                = each.value["virtual_network_name"]
  resource_group_name = each.value["resource_group_name"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  for_each             = var.subnet
  name                 = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name  = each.value["resource_group_name"] #"${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}" 
  virtual_network_name = each.value["virtual_network_name"]
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = each.value["endpoint_network_policies"]
  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies  = each.value["service_network_policies"]

  dynamic "delegation" {
     for_each = var.delegation != null ? var.delegation : []
     content {
       name = lookup(delegation.value, "name", null)
       service_delegation {
         name    = lookup(delegation.value.service_delegation, "name", null)
         actions = lookup(delegation.value.service_delegation, "actions", null)
       }
     }
   }
}
```

When ever i am running the plan for it with existing subnet and creating new subnet the plan says "No changes" as it is not able to detect the service delegation change

Please help me

---

```
subnet = {

    snet1 = {

        name = "Practicerg1-snet1"
        resource_group_name  = "Practicerg1"
        virtual_network_name = "Practicerg1-vnet"
        address_prefixes     = ["10.2.0.0/24"]
        endpoint_network_policies = true
        service_network_policies  = true
        
        delegation = {
          name = "snet1delegation"
          service_delegation = {
            name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
          }
        }

    }
    snet2 = {

        name = "Practicerg3-snet1"
        resource_group_name  = "Practicerg3"
        virtual_network_name = "Practicerg3-vnet"
        address_prefixes     = ["10.4.0.0/24"]
        endpoint_network_policies = true
        service_network_policies  = true

        delegation = {
          name = "snet1delegation"
          service_delegation = {
            name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
          }
        }
        
    }

    snet3 = {

        name = "Practicerg2-snet1"
        resource_group_name  = "Practicerg2"
        virtual_network_name = "Practicerg2-vnet"
        address_prefixes     = ["10.3.0.0/24"]
        endpoint_network_policies = true
        service_network_policies  = true

        delegation = {
          name = "snet1delegation"
          service_delegation = {
            name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
          }
        }
        
    }

    snet4 = {

        name = "Practicerg2-snet2"
        resource_group_name  = "Practicerg2"
        virtual_network_name = "Practicerg2-vnet"
        address_prefixes     = ["10.3.1.0/27"]
        endpoint_network_policies = true
        service_network_policies  = true

        delegation = {
          name = "snet1delegation"
          service_delegation = {
            name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
          }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is my var file where i declare value for the delegation, still not creating while apply

---

As per your latest comment i created new subnet and the plan is below

Terraform will perform the following actions:

```
# module.terraform.module.subnet.azurerm_subnet.snet["snet4"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
      + address_prefix                                 = (known after apply)
      + address_prefixes                               = [
          + "10.3.1.0/27",
        ]
      + enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
      + enforce_private_link_service_network_policies  = true
      + id                                             = (known after apply)
      + name                                           = "Practicerg2-snet2"
      + resource_group_name                            = "Practicerg2"
      + virtual_network_name                           = "Practicerg2-vnet"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Not able to attach images due to lack of some previliges

Comment: "When ever i am running the plan for it with existing subnet and creating new subnet the plan says "No changes" as it is not able to detect the service delegation change" 
 are you importing the existing subnet first and then changing the delegation setting ?
or are you overall creating a new subnet with delegated setting in the exisiting vnet?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT i am creating overall a new subnet with delegate setting

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you can try the below code, I tested the below for ***creating totally 3 subnets*** where ***2 are created with service delegation*** and ***another one without service delegation***  :

`main.tf`

```
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
  name                = "ansumantest"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" { 
  name                = "ansuman-vnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  for_each             = var.subnet
  name                 = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = each.value["endpoint_network_policies"]
  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies  = each.value["service_network_policies"]

  dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "delegation", {}) != {} ? [1] : []
     content {
       name = lookup(each.value.delegation, "name", null)
       service_delegation {
         name    = lookup(each.value.delegation.service_delegation, "name", null)
         actions = lookup(each.value.delegation.service_delegation, "actions", null)
       }
     }
   }
}
```

`variable.tf`

```
variable "subnet"{
    default = {
     subnet1={
         name="subnet1"
         address_prefixes=["10.0.1.0/24"]
         endpoint_network_policies= true
         service_network_policies=true
         delegation = {
            name="delegation1"
            service_delegation={
                name= "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
                actions= ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
            }
         }
     }
     subnet2={
         name="subnet2"
         address_prefixes=["10.0.2.0/24"]
         endpoint_network_policies= true
         service_network_policies=true
         delegation = {
            name="delegation2"
            service_delegation={
                name= "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters"
                actions= ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
            }
        }
    }
    subnet3={
         name="subnet3"
         address_prefixes=["10.0.3.0/24"]
         endpoint_network_policies= true
         service_network_policies=true
         delegation = {}
        }
}
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have edited my code as per ur code but still terraform is still not able to pickup the change

Also wanted to check if 
endpoint_network_policies= true, service_network_policies=true are mandatory to set as true in order to create the service delegation

Comment: Ok Agree but it is not creating the delegation also

Comment: @Sudhansu, you have to do a terraform apply -auto-approve not terraform plan for the code to create the resources

Comment: what i meant is terraform apply is also no creating the delegation, neither am i able to see the delegation in portal

Comment: @Sudhansu, can you please share the screen shot of the terraform apply and the subnets from portal like i have shared .. in your question .. so that i can take a look ?